# Can I modify the workspace files from an extesion

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to modify the workspace files / folders from an extension in vscode. I have been looking around and couldn't find a way to do so.

I notices there is `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders` but it's readonly.

Is there a way to do it?

### motive

We have a big project with alout of files in different folders with the same name or closely related names. I want to be able to show just the files that interest me at the moment, so navigation is easier, and I don't modify files that don't interest me at the moment.

### example

If I have a file structure like this:

```
├───a
│   ├───folder_a
│   │       file1
│   │       file2
│   │
│   └───folder_b
│           file1
│           file2
│
└───b
    ├───folder_a
    │       file1
    │       file2
    │
    └───folder_b
            file1
            file2
```

I want just to choose whether I see just "folder_a", "folder_b" or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more than one folder in your workspace in vscode.

[see here vscode doc](http://You%20can%20add%20more%20than%20one%20folder%20in%20your%20workspace%20in%20vscode.)